# What about these exposures to paint with lead in it?

Tags: paint, lead

1. About three years ago, we renovated two bathrooms. The larger one I (total amateur) did. I knew from a test that the paint was oil-based (and painted years before, so assume it had lead in it), so used a heavy and smelly primer over that before using latex paint. Where there were some uneven spaces, I used a sander, and sand paper to even things out. I believe I wore a mask and goggles. I recall some paint dust in the air, not much. I haven't had any new respiratory symptoms since.
2. The other bathroom I TRIED to do, and used that orange gel stuff to peel back the paint (some of which was latex). I made such a mess of it that we hired a friend of a family member, who is a professional painter. He spent about a day or two in that bathroom, priming, sanding, painting (not sure what order the sanding and priming was). I'm not sure how much lead paint was left on those old walls after all of my orange gel-removal work, but if there was some, could he have been exposed and ill from it? I don't believe he did a lead test on the paint before working.

So, in either of these instances, anyone know the possibility of our having been (or being today, several years later) in danger of lead exposure? Is there any way to test for it? Thank you.

Comment: I think lead mainly affects the brain and needs long term exposure, like asbestos which affects the lungs.  Young are more affected.  Short limited exposure probably much better than sanding/eating/chewing lead paint everyday.  Your health professional can test for for lead exposure and it will probably come back positive.  I might not be the most perfect but close and I grew up with lead in gasoline.

Comment: You can have a blood test for lead, though you may have to deal with whether your insurance will pay for one, or you get stuck with the bill.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because nobody can guestimate the danger from a vague question. If you're concerned, go to your doctor and get everyone tested for lead poisoning.

Answer (score 3):

I doubt anyone can tell the possibilty of you being in danger of lead exposure. You can get a simple blood test can tell if you've got lead poisoning. Most of the lead that enters the body is pased through your system throught normal bodily functions. Why are you asking his?

Comment: because we recently had the walls in another room tested for lead in anticipation of getting those walls painted, and the test came back positive. That led to family discussion about our painting the bathrooms several years ago and I'm worried about the painter, and my own exposure. Wondering if a person can get seriously ill from these two experiences/exposures. And I'm REALLY glad to read that most of the lead would pass through our system. May that be the case!

Comment: @Annabanana  I think most of the concern is with young children being expose to small long term(eating paint, drinking water from lead pipes) lead.  Do not know of short term minor exposure for us older people.  Imagine a major/heavy exposure might not be good, but a simple mask/eye protection and washing the room down is enough, except to lawyers.

Comment: The issue is normally kids eating/ingesting paint dust and flakes from degrading paint. If the paint is not flaking and you've thoroughly cleaned out the dust from when it was sanded, I wouldn't worry.